# Display top 10 results in codeigniter and display 1st, 2nd and 3rd top values

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, codeigniter

I am getting output page like this (Shown in below screenshot[image: refer below image])

I want gold image to be display to top scorers and silver to second topper and bronze to others

I am using code like this

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> ScoreBoard</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
           <div class="col-sm-12">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered">

                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                            $total_exams1 = $this->db->select('title_id')   
                                    ->from('exam_title')
                                    ->count_all_results();

                                $b1 = $this->db->select('*, (sum(result.result_percent)) / '.$total_exams1.' as percent')   
                                                    ->group_by('users.user_id')                                     
                                                    ->from('result')
                                                    ->order_by("percent", "desc" )
                                                    ->join('users', 'users.user_id = result.user_id', 'left')
                                                    ->join('states', 'users.state = states.state_id', 'left')
                                                    ->join('user_zone', 'users.user_zone = user_zone.user_zone_id', 'left')
                                                    ->limit("10")
                                                    ->get()
                                                ->result(); 
                            $j = 1; 
                            foreach($b1 as $z) {                                            
                        ?>
                            <tr class="<?= ($i & 1) ? 'even' : 'odd'; ?>">                                    
                                <td style="width:5%;"><?php echo $j; ?></td> 
                                    <?php if($z->image == "") { ?>
                                <td class="hidden-x" style="width:35%;">    
                                    <img class="userImgTop10n" src="<?php echo base_url('user-avatar/avatar-placeholder.jpg') ?>" alt="Profile Picture" />
                                    <div class="image_righ">
                                        <b><?php echo $z->user_name; ?></b><br>
                                        <?php echo $z->state_name; ?><br>
                                        <?php echo $z->user_zone_name; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </td>                                   
                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                <td class="hidden-x" >
                                    <img class="userImgTop10n" src="<?php echo base_url("user-avatar/".$z->image); ?>" alt="Profile Picture" />
                                    <div class="image_righ">
                                        <b><?php echo $z->user_name; ?></b><br>
                                        <?php echo $z->state_name; ?><br>
                                        <?php echo $z->user_zone_name; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </td>                                   
                                    <?php } ?>          
                                <?php                   
                                    $exams_attended1 = $this->db->select('title_id')    
                                        ->where('user_id', $z->user_id)
                                        ->from('result')
                                        ->group_by('user_id')
                                        ->count_all_results();
                                ?>
                                <td class="hidden-xxs"><b><?php echo $exams_attended1; ?></b><br>Exams Attended</td>
                                <td class="hidden-xxs"><b><?php echo $total_exams1; ?></b><br>Total Exams</td>
                                <td class="hidden-x">
                                    <b><?php echo round($z->percent, 2); ?> %</b><br>Avg Result 
                                          <div class="badge_righ">
                                          <?php if($j == 1) { ?>                                              
                                          <span><img class="userBadge" src="<?php echo base_url('Badge_Gold.png') ?>" alt="Badge Gold" /></span>                                             
                                          <?php } 
                                          if($j == 2) { ?>                                           
                                          <span><img class="userBadge" src="<?php echo base_url('Badge_Silver.png') ?>" alt="Badge Gold" /></span>                                            
                                          <?php } if($j > 2) { ?>                                              
                                          <span><img class="userBadge" src="<?php echo base_url('Badge_Bronze.png') ?>" alt="Badge Gold" /></span>                                    
                                          <?php } ?>
                                          </div>
                                </td>                                   
                            </tr>
                            <?php 
                            $j++;
                                }
                            ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in the above screenshot first 3 rows should be gold images (because of same marks).

Comment: try another order by in your query based on your medal

Comment: For this you will have to decide the range for the percentage that you want to be appear in the topper list. What you have done is corrcect instead of comapring with 1 or 2 use the Avg percentage value for it. And display the list based on Avg percentage

Comment: i am using gold medal for 1st row and silver medal for second row and bronze for others. i want medals to be shown based on marks, pls sujjest me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary array containing unique reverse sorted average scores. Then, when giving medals, instead of checking for places (1st, 2nd, 3rd...), check if the score matches the 1st, 2nd or 3rd score from that temporary array.

For the screenshot you posted, the array would look like:

```
$scores = [92.5, 90, 87.5];
```

and the gold medals would be all the scores with the score of `$scores[0]`, the silver ones are `$scores[1]` and the bronzes would be `$scores[2]` (unless you want *everyone* else to get bronze).

Comment: It doesn't matter, the temp array will be generated after each query based on the query results.

Comment: if $scores[0] and $scores[1] are same then i need to display gold for both scores. how can i do for this?

Comment: Please read my answer... They **cannot** be the same because the array needs to be **unique** and **reverse sorted**...   http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php